# The artifact was found in the local repository but you have explicitly stated that it should be downloaded from a remote one"

Tags: spring-boot, testing, contract, spring-cloud-contract, aether

I have consumer project, which has spring cloud contract tests verifier,which needs to talk to the stubs jar in the remote repo. The setup for `stubsMode: LOCAL` works fine, but for remote it throws the following error.

```
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.cloud.contract.stubrunner.BatchStubRunner]: Factory method 'batchStubRunner' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: The artifact was found in the local repository but you have explicitly stated that it should be downloaded from a remote one
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:185)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiate(ConstructorResolver.java:622)
    ... 43 more
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: The artifact was found in the local repository but you have explicitly stated that it should be downloaded from a remote one
```

Consumer Side remote code:

```
`@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest(classes = RestClientConfig.class,
        webEnvironment = SpringBootTest.WebEnvironment.MOCK)
@AutoConfigureStubRunner(   repositoryRoot="https://nexus.com/nexus/content/repositories/sam-releases/com/sam/api/",
        ids = "com.sam:api:+:stubs:8083",
        stubsMode = StubRunnerProperties.StubsMode.REMOTE
)
```

pom.xml

```
<spring-cloud.version>Finchley.SR2</spring-cloud.version>
    <spring-cloud-contract.version>2.0.2.RELEASE</spring-cloud-contract-version>
```

I need to use REMOTE repoUrl for the consumer project to talk to the producer stub jar.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you read the documentation at this section https://cloud.spring.io/spring-cloud-static/Finchley.SR2/single/spring-cloud.html#_ci_server_setup (it's actually enough to find the exception you were looking for in the documentation) you'll see the following text:

> 91.4 CI Server setup
>
> When fetching stubs / contracts in a CI, shared environment, what
>   might happen is that both the producer and the consumer reuse the same
>   local Maven repository. Due to this, the framework, responsible for
>   downloading a stub JAR from remote location, can’t decide which JAR
>   should be picked, local or remote one. That caused the "The artifact
>   was found in the local repository but you have explicitly stated that
>   it should be downloaded from a remote one" exception and failed the
>   build.
>
> For such cases we’re introducing the property and plugin setup
>   mechanism:
>
> ```
> via stubrunner.snapshot-check-skip system property
> via STUBRUNNER_SNAPSHOT_CHECK_SKIP environment variable
> ```
>
> if either of these values is set to true, then the stub downloader
>   will not verify the origin of the downloaded JAR.
>
> For the plugins you need to set the contractsSnapshotCheckSkip
>   property to true.

Just follow the guidelines from the documentation and you won't have this problem anymore. Or bump to Greenwich release train where this issue got completely fixed.

Comment: Yup. So you should remove local m2 entries for your stubs before running this

Comment: Marcin, but the actual point here really is that, we need to check from the remote url right ? What's the point skipping the snapshot check ? even if a fake url is kept it will work.

Comment: It will not. If you remove the local m2 entries it will fail to download them from a remote repo and it won't pick any cached versions since you've removed them

Comment: I suggest bumping to greenwich and the whole problem will be gone

Comment: If changing version to Greenwich, do I need to change in both producer & consumer project ?

Comment: Can you also suggest what other dependencies would be required for `Greenwhich.RELEASE` verison ?

Comment: Best to Upgrade both but client would be enough. You need to upgrade boot to 2.1.x

Comment: Also there's greenwich sr1 there

Comment: Marcin, Instead of all that, I have tried with my old versions only & just used the environment value. I deleted from m2 repo & kept fake url, so as expected it failed. I kept the correct url, and now it passed. It seems to be working with that way. Thanks a lot for your help.